# C# accessing protected member in derived class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, encapsulation, protected, derived-class

*I wrote the following code:*

```
public class A                             
{
    protected string Howdy = "Howdy!";     
}

public class B : A                           
{
    public void CallHowdy()
    {
        A a = new A();
        Console.WriteLine(a.Howdy);
    }
}
```

Now, in `VS2010` it results in the following compilation error:

> Cannot access protected member 'A.a' via a qualifier of type 'A'; the qualifier must be of type 'B' (or derived from it).

This seems quite illogical to me - why can't I access the `protected` field of the class instance from a method of the class, which is derived from it?

So, **why does this happen**?

---

*Found a strict answer* - https://web.archive.org/web/20101104024941/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/09/491031.aspx

Comment: +1 for a very clearly written question. :)

Comment: What you can do is create a protected static method that provides access only to a derived class, like so:

public class A                             
{
    protected string Howdy = "Howdy!";     
}

public class B : A                           
{
    public void CallHowdy()
    {
        A a = new A();
        Console.WriteLine(a.Howdy);
    }
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not accessing it from inside the class, you're trying to access the variable as though it were `public`. You would not expect this to compile, and this is pretty much what you are trying to do:

```
public class SomethingElse
{
    public void CallHowdy()
    {
        A a = new A();
        Console.WriteLine(a.Howdy);
    }
}
```

There is no relationship, and it sounds like you are confused why that field is not public.

Now, you could do this, if you wanted to:

```
public class B : A
{
    public void CallHowdy()
    {
        Console.Writeline(Howdy);
    }
}
```

Because `B` has inherited the data from `A` in this instance.

Comment: Well, actually, I was confused by the possibility to do that in `PHP5` (I also asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653991/php5-member-visibility). Difference like this should probably have a strong reason behind it, don't you think so?

Comment: Well, PHP seems to be the odd one there, as it seems to be exposing a protected variable illegally. There are more strict type boundaries than PHP in C# it seems.

Comment: I am also confused by the fact that everyone in the corresponding `PHP` question keeps telling me things like *"Why shouldn't it be accessible? That's perfectly valid".* I guess this question is more about certain coding habits.

Comment: `B` has access to the protected data of it's _own instance_, not to the values of _other instances_.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
public class B : A                           
{
    public void CallHowdy()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Howdy);
    }
}
```

In your code, you're trying to access Howdy from outside an A, not from within a B. Here, you are inside a B, and can therefore access the protected member in A.

Answer (score 1):

A protected member of a base class is accessible in a derived class only if the access takes place through the derived class type.

You are getting error because because A is not derived from B.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A protected member is only visible to itself and derived members.  In your case, the declaration of A implies that only public members are accessible, just as if you instantiated an A from any other class. You could, however, simply write this.Howdy, because, due to the derivation chain, Howdy is available from inside of class B.