# C# protected field access

Tags: c#, private, encapsulation, protected

*(This question is a follow-up to [C# accessing protected member in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657545/c-sharp-accessing-protected-member-in-derived-class))*

I have the following code snippet:

```
public class Fox
{
    protected string FurColor;
    private string furType;

    public void PaintFox(Fox anotherFox)
    {
        anotherFox.FurColor = "Hey!";
        anotherFox.furType = "Hey!";
    }
}

public class RedFox : Fox
{
    public void IncorrectPaintFox(Fox anotherFox)
    {
        // This one is inaccessible here and results in a compilation error.
        anotherFox.FurColor = "Hey!";
    }

    public void CorrectPaintFox(RedFox anotherFox)
    {
        // This is perfectly valid.
        anotherFox.FurColor = "Hey!";
    }
}
```

- Now, we know that [private and protected fields are private and protected for type, not instance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983553/why-are-private-fields-private-to-the-type-not-the-instance)
- We also know that access modifiers should work at compile time.
- So, here is the question - **why can't I access the `FurColor` field of the `Fox` class instance in `RedFox`?** `RedFox` is derived from `Fox`, so the compiler knows it has access to the corresponding protected fields.
- Also, as you can see in `CorrectPaintFox`, I can access the protected field of the `RedFox` class instance. **So, why can't I expect the same from the `Fox` class instance?**

Comment: There's a [blog post by Eric Lippert on that topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/09/491031.aspx).

Comment: Why? Because this is how the language was specified: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691129(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple reason is:

```
public void IncorrectPaintFox(Fox anotherFox)
{
    anotherFox = new BlueFox();

    // This one is inaccessible here and results in a compilation error.
    anotherFox.FurColor = "Hey!";
}
```

Now you're not accessing the protected field from within `BlueFox`, therefore since the compiler doesn't know what the runtime type is, it has to always make this an error.

Comment: +1 people always forget about sibling classes...

Answer (score 2):

To expand slightly on the accepted answer, the *reason* the compiler enforces this rule, as opposed to the much more lax meaning of `protected` that PHP has, is because allowing the access you want to allow would make it possible to break the invariants of a class, by bypassing its defined protection levels. (Of course, this is always possible e.g. via Reflection, but the compiler at least makes it hard to do *by accident*).

The problem is that just knowing that some object is a `Fox` does not make it safe for you to interact with its internal workings, because it may not *actually be* a `Fox` at 
runtime. Consider these classes:

```
public class Fox
{
  protected Color FurColor;
}

public class RedFox
{
  public RedFox () 
  { 
    this.FurColor = Color.Red; 
  }
}

public class ArcticFox
{
  public ArcticFox () 
  { 
    this.FurColor = Color.White; 
  }
}
```

What you are asking is for the compiler to permit the following method, assuming it was defined on the `RedFox` class:

```
public void PaintFoxRed ( Fox fox )
{
    fox.FurColor = Color.Red;
}
```

But if that were legal, I could do this:

```
RedFox a = new RedFox();
Fox b = new ArcticFox();
a.PaintFoxRed(b);
```

My `ArcticFox` is now red despite the class itself only allowing itself to be white.